# How to replace hypotheses `0 < d` with `S d'` in Coq?

Tags: functional-programming, coq

> How to replace hypotheses `0 < d` with `S d'` in Coq?

In Coq, I've the annoying hypotheses that `0 < d`, which I need to replace to apply `euclid_div_succ_d_theorem` to prove `euclid_div_theorem` as a corollary.

How can I somehow convert the assumptions into the proper form to apply the theorem?

```
Theorem euclid_div_theorem :
  forall d : nat,
    0 < d -> 
    forall n : nat,
    exists q r : nat,
      n = q * d + r /\ r < d.

Theorem euclid_div_succ_d_theorem :
  forall d : nat,
  forall n : nat,
  exists q r : nat,
    n = q * (S d) + r /\ r < (S d).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the standard lemmas from the `Arith` module you can change `0 < d` into `exists m, d = S m`, which (after destruction) gives you the desired result.

```
Require Import Arith.

Theorem euclid_div_theorem : forall d : nat,
    0 < d -> forall n : nat, exists q r : nat, n = q * d + r /\ r < d.
Proof.
  intros d H n.
  apply Nat.lt_neq, Nat.neq_sym, Nat.neq_0_r in H.
  destruct H; rewrite H.
  apply euclid_div_succ_d_theorem.
Qed.
```

Here is how I did it:

`Search (exists _, _ = S _).` gives us the last lemma (it's easier to go backwards from your goal here, imho):

```
Nat.neq_0_r: forall n : nat, n <> 0 <-> (exists m : nat, n = S m)
```

This means we need to infer `d <> 0` from `0 < d`, so again `Search (_ < _ -> _ <> _).` yields:

```
Nat.lt_neq: forall n m : nat, n < m -> n <> m
```

Now it's easy to see that we need to swap the lhs and rhs of the inequality, so I did `Search (?x <> ?y -> ?y <> ?x).`:

```
Nat.neq_sym: forall n m : nat, n <> m -> m <> n
```

I could've also used a more universal lemma:

```
not_eq_sym: forall (A : Type) (x y : A), x <> y -> y <> x
```

It'd give us the same result.

---

There is, however, a less tedious way of proving the lemma -- you can always use `destruct d.` and prove it by cases:

```
  intros d H n.
  destruct d.
  - inversion H.   (* H is a contradiction now: `0 < 0` *)
  - apply euclid_div_succ_d_theorem.
```

Comment: Thank you @AntonTrunov. This is one of those cases when I know what to do on paper, but cannot express it in Coq. I appreciate your support.

Comment: In proving the other theorem as a corollary, how do you introduce an implication as an assumption? I only know of assert.

Comment: `pose proof` or `specialize` work kind of like `assert`. It depends on your  particular situation what works best (or could be applied at all).

Comment: Here, would you assert d > 0?  However, d could be any natural number. I somehow need to replace (S d) with d' and introduce the assumption that d' > 0? However, I don't know how to express this :(

Comment: One variant is to treat `S d` as a whole and use `assert (S d > 0) by apply gt_Sn_O.`.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand you, but I think you don't have to do the replacement -- you can operate with `S d`.

Comment: Ahh exactly... my mistake.